# How to make vim abbreviations not work in comment areas?

Tags: vim

I have  a list of abbreviations,

```
iab uppercase UPPERCASE
iab lowercase LOWERCASE
```

(case specific issues).

I'm trying to make them not work in comment areas (i.e. in lines which start with a certain character), because they mess up my normal comment text. Has anyone any ideas how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to test the context. I've already written a [few functions](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets#The_VimL_library) to help define such abbreviations:

```
inoreab uppercase <c-r>=MapNoContext('uppercase', 'UPPERCASE')<cr>
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Very useful indeed. Thank you.

Comment: why is it `inoreab` and not just `iabb`?

Comment: The `nore` versions are always to be the default. Sometimes other users/plugins make strange choices like remapping `<cr>` in one mode or another. In that case though, it should have not any impact.